# Auto Fit Excel Column Width based on Column Names in Row 1

Tags: vba, excel, width

Code below auto-fits column as per data in it even if Range is selected for only first row which contain column names.

Lets consider that Sheet has the handle to required Sheet. I want columns from C to F to be auto-fit.

```
Sheet.Range("C1:F1").Columns.AutoFit
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840.aspx

I would like to see full column name without the need of resizing manually.

Comment: I do not understand, You want only C1:F1 to be autofit, or the whole columns(C:F)?

Comment: I want whole columns to be autofit based on my column name width as they have maximum length than data. I tried Sheet.Range(C:F).Columns.AutoFit. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the cell value and formatting from C1:F1 to an unused column to the right and use [Range.AutoFit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840.aspx) . Use the adjusted width to set the column width of the original.

```
Dim c As Long, cc As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    cc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    For c = 3 To 6
        .Cells(1, c).Copy Destination:=.Cells(1, cc)
        .Columns(cc).AutoFit
        .Columns(c).ColumnWidth = .Columns(cc).ColumnWidth
    Next c
    .Columns(cc).Cells.Clear
End With
```

This will adjust each column width based on the formatted header row only.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I  am still novice in VBA. Could you please let me know what does this line mean :                                                                cc = .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

Comment: It finds the first empty column looking right-to-left. The empty column is used as a surregate to calculate column width with .AutoFit.